# Maximum Sum Increasing Subsequence(but the output is a list)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Write a recursive program to find the list of elements that make up the sum of maximum sum subsequence of the given array such that the integers in the subsequence are sorted in increasing order.

For example, if input is `{1, 101, 2, 3, 100, 4, 5}`, then output should be `[1,2,3,100]` (1+2+3+100 is the highest sum)

I tried this but I don't think it helps at all(I do not get dynamic programming yet and I think this code does not help my issue).

```
s = [3, 1, 6, 2, 8, 10]
rez=[]
max_prev=0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i]>max_prev:
        max_prev=s[i]
        rez.append(s[i])
print(rez)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: is it a task for us? Nice. What we'll get? Please show us what you tried, so that we can help you in fixing your code. We are not here to complete your home-work, but we are ready to help you with your problems

Comment: if you are not able to solve problem then, a single web search as question can give you tutorials and solution

Comment: i do not know how to solve it at all since i don t really get dynamic programming yet,so since i do not know how to do anything regarding this i thought someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list of ascending series (i.e. list of lists) and then use max() to get the one with the largest sum:

```
A = [1, 101, 2, 3, 100, 4, 5]

series = [A[:1]]
for a in A[1:]:
    more = [s+[a] for s in series if s[-1]<=a] # add series where ascending
    series.extend([[a]]+more)                  # each value starts a new series

result = max(series,key=sum)
print(result)
# [1, 2, 3, 100]
```

[EDIT] to be more memory efficient, you can use a recursive approach where you take the maximum of the subset that skips the first element compared to the subset that includes uses it (with remaining elements that are greater than the 1st one).

```
def maxAscendingSum(A):
    if len(A)<2: return A
    skipping  = maxAscendingSum(A[1:])
    using     = A[:1] + maxAscendingSum([a for a in A[1:] if a>A[0]])
    return max((skipping,using),key=sum)
```

To make that recursive function even more efficient, you can use memoization to keep track of previous results and avoid doing the same work more than once:

```
def maxAscendingSum(A,memo=None):
    if len(A)<2: return A
    if memo is None: memo = dict()
    key = tuple(A)
    if key not in memo:
        skipping  = maxAscendingSum(A[1:],memo)
        using     = A[:1] + maxAscendingSum([a for a in A[1:] if a>A[0]],memo)
        memo[key] =  max((skipping,using),key=sum)
    return memo[key]
```

Comment: It certainly works. However, it has created too many `intermediate` sublists for the final comparison to get the `max` one.  (it seems some room for improvement?) Ex. for 12-numbers list - this will create 527 sublists.